# Having trouble returning a variable java

Tags: java, static, return, bank

```
public class Account
{
static int accountNum;
static int nextAccountNum = 112200;
static double balance;


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Account checkingAccount = new Account(1500.00);
        Account savingAccount = new Account(1000.00);
        Account moneyMarketAccount = new Account(500.00);

        checkingAccount.getAccountNumber();
        savingAccount.getAccountNumber();
        moneyMarketAccount.getAccountNumber();

    }

    public Account(double bal)
    {
        balance = bal;
        accountNum = nextAccountNum;
        nextAccountNum++;
    }

}
```

Every time I run it, I don't get any return variables. All I see is the process completed text. Looking for help

Comment: What are you expecting to get? Printouts?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't output anything.  Use `System.out.println` to output the account balances, e.g.

```
System.out.println(checkingAccount.getAccountNumber());
```

Also, make your `accountNum` and your `balance` variables non-`static`, or else the balance and account numbers will get overwritten with each new instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's often good practice to separate the main function from an class which will have several instances. Getters and setters methods are used for proper encapsulation of class variables, as an account probably should have. An example is below.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Account checkingAccount = new Account(1,1500.00);
        Account savingAccount = new Account(2,1000.00);
        Account moneyMarketAccount = new Account(3,500.00);

        System.out.println("Account " + checkingAccount.getAccountNumber() 
                + " has balance of: " + checkingAccount.getBalance());
        System.out.println("Account " + savingAccount.getAccountNumber() 
                + " has balance of: " + savingAccount.getBalance());
        System.out.println("Account " + moneyMarketAccount.getAccountNumber() 
                + " has balance of: " + moneyMarketAccount.getBalance());
    }
}
```

**Account.java**

```
public class Account
{
private int accountNum;
private int nextAccountNum = 112200;
private double balance;

    public Account(int accountNum, double balance)
    {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.accountNum = accountNum;
    }

    public int getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNum;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        // check if balance variable is a correct value
        // before setting it to the class variable
        this.balance = balance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `accountNum` and `balance` are declared `static`. You need them to be instance fields so each instance of `Account` has its own values.

The reason you get no output is that your `main()` method creates several `Account` objects but doesn't do anything with them.

```
public class Account
{
    static int nextAccountNum = 112200;
    int accountNum;
    double balance;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Account checkingAccount = new Account(1500.00);
        Account savingAccount = new Account(1000.00);
        Account moneyMarketAccount = new Account(500.00);

        checkingAccount.getAccountNumber();
        savingAccount.getAccountNumber();
        moneyMarketAccount.getAccountNumber();

        System.out.println("Checking: " + checkingAccount.toString());    
        System.out.println("Savings: " + savingAccount.toString());    
        System.out.println("Money market: " + moneyMarketAccount.toString());    
    }

    public Account(double bal)
    {
        balance = bal;
        accountNum = nextAccountNum;
        nextAccountNum++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account " + accountNum + ": balance=" + balance;
    }    
}
```